# Outlook stealing spacebar press from Addin owned WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, outlook, outlook-addin, addin-express

I have an Outlook Addin (Office 2013) which main role is to open an WPF window containing the WebBrowser, which embeds the specific business Web Application. I already had to solve several issues with WPF WebBrowser not receiving specific keystrokes like enter,delete, ctrl+c, ctrl-v etc. This however was successfully handled by approach described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2010/04/08/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in/.

Those issues were at least consistent. The last one I am facing relates to spacebar. In general space is treated similar to other alphanumeric keys and it does not require intercepting. This is not true however in all the cases. Whenever user focuses Outlook on specific Email (by focusing I don't mean selecting email in the navigation pane, but rather clicking on the body of the email in the right-main pane) then Outlook uses spacebar as a navigation shortcut. This way user is able to browse through email content and switching to next emails.

Problem appears when user after focusing on right pane, opens my Addin WPF window and uses HTML box to provide text containing spaces. In that state Outlook is still  navigating in the Outlook Explorer underneath, "stealing" spacebar hit, even though WPF window is the one active, not Outlook Explorer. This means Web App never receives the space. Only when User "loses focus" from the current email, even by clicking on the current displayed email in navigation pane, then Outlook seems to release the ownership over spacebar and it works as expected again.

I see 2 potential solutions for the problem:

1. Whenever Addin WPF window is activated, to force Outlook explorer to loose focus from the currently displayed email in right-main pane. I have not yet found a way to achieve it though.
2. Intercept the space and trigger the predefined javascript method to inject space. This however it tricky, because in cases when spacebar works correctly, my Addin would receive 2 spaces - one by simply receiving the spacebar hit and second by injection.

Any ideas how to solve such problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Open the WPF window in the new thread.
In this way, all keystrokes like ctrl-c ctrl-v ctrl-a enter delete tab and spacebar will work.

```
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
    window.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}));
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();
```